# Connect carry out to carry in for adder/subtractor in structural VHDL

Tags: vhdl

So I have the following VHDL code to implement an Nbit adder/subtractor using only a 2:1 mux, an inverter (flips bit), and a full adder. I am having issues connecting the carry out of an adder to the next ones carry in while having the first adder have a carry in of i_Control. Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

```
    library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.all;

entity add_subtract is
  generic(N   : integer := 16);
  port(i_M    : in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
       i_N    : in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
       i_Control  : in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
       o_S    : out std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0));

end add_subtract;

architecture structure of add_subtract is

component bit_adder
    port(i_X     : in std_logic;
             i_Y     : in std_logic;
             i_Cin   : in std_logic;
             o_Ss    : out std_logic;
         o_Couts : out std_logic);
end component;

component inverter
    port(i_A  : in std_logic;
         o_F  : out std_logic);
end component;

component bit_mux
    port(i_X  : in std_logic;
         i_Y  : in std_logic;
             i_S  : in std_logic;
             o_N  : out std_logic);
end component;

signal compvalue, muxvalue, addervalue : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
signal sel, carry : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
signal k : integer := 0;
begin

carry(0) <= i_Control(0);

G1: for i in 0 to N-1 generate
one_comp: inverter
    port map(i_A     => i_N(i),
         o_F     => compvalue(i));

mux: bit_mux
    port map(i_X     => i_N(i),
         i_Y     => compvalue(i),
         i_S     => i_Control(i),
         o_N     => muxvalue(i));

struct_adder: bit_adder
    port map(i_X     => i_M(i),
         i_Y     => muxvalue(i),
         i_Cin   => carry(i),
         o_Ss    => o_S(i),
         o_Couts => carry(i));

end generate;

end structure;
```

Comment: Homework. Nobody implements a subtractor like this. Just type `c <= a-b;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the carry array one longer:

```
signal carry : std_logic_vector(N downto 0); -- was N-1
```

and change this:

```
     o_Couts => carry(i));
```

to this:

```
     o_Couts => carry(i+1));
```

in your generate statement while leaving the i_Cin carry input association as is.

If the last carry out isn't conveyed through an output port the net will get eaten during synthesis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your suggestion got the adder/subtractor working properly :)